# Why my Dart implementation of an asm checksum macro does not work?

Tags: dart, assembly, masm, checksum, crc32

I'm trying to implement a 32bits checksum macro written in masm32 to the Dart language.
Here is what I understood: the checksum function takes a String as input and returns the checksum in a 4 bytes integer.
But I don't get the same result.
Does anyone see my errors please?

```
; ecx : length of String variable
; esi : pointer to String variable
; eax : 'return' value of calculated checksum
CHECKSUM32_MACRO MACRO 
   LOCAL Checksum32Loop, Checksum32Done       
        xor     eax,eax
        cmp     ecx,4
        jb      Checksum32Done
    align 16
    Checksum32Loop:
        mov     ebx,dword ptr [esi]
        add     eax,ebx
        shl     ebx,1
        adc     ebx,1
        xor     eax,ebx
        add     esi,4
        sub     ecx,4
        jz      Checksum32Done
        cmp     ecx,4
        jae     Checksum32Loop       
        mov     edx,4        
        sub     edx,ecx        
        sub     esi,edx
        mov     ecx,4
        jmp     Checksum32Loop
   Checksum32Done:     
ENDM
```

```
int checksum(String src){
  int i = src.length-1;
  int res = 0;
  do{
    int c  = src.codeUnitAt(i);
    res += c;
    String cBits = c.toRadixString(2);
    int bitFort = int.parse(cBits[0]);
    
    int transform = c << 1;
    transform = transform + 1 + bitFort;
    res = res ^ transform;   
    i--;
  }while(i>=0);  
  return res;
}
```

I modified the code according to the advice, with as postulate an ASCII string so always multiple of 4, the time to understand the problem.
It still doesn't work though.

```
String deComp = File(CHEMIN_FICHIER_DECOMP).readAsStringSync();

List<int> encoded = [];
for (int i =0; i<deComp.length; i++){
    List<int> cUtf8 = utf8.encode(deComp[i]);
    encoded.addAll(cUtf8);
}
print(checksum_stack(encoded));

_______

int checksum_stack(List<int> src){
  int i = 0;
  int res = 0;
  do{
    int c  = fusion(src.sublist(i, i+4));
    res += c;
    String cBits = c.toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0');
    int bitFort = int.parse(cBits[0]);

    int transform = c << 1;
    transform = transform + 1 +bitFort;
    res = res ^ transform;
    i+=4;
  }while(i < src.length-4);
  return res;
}

int fusion(List<int> str){
  if (str.length != 4) {
    throw "need multiple of 4!";
  }
  String hexStr = "";
  str.forEach((c) {
    hexStr += c.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0');
  });  
  return int.parse(hexStr,radix: 16);
}
```

Comment: Are your characters 4 bytes each? Does your input `esi` point to the characters directly?

Comment: I don't know, sorry
In the C++ (caller) :
`char * pData;
pData =(char *)malloc(nFilesize);
ReadFile(hInputFile, (void *)pData, nFilesize, $nBytesRead, 0);
masmfunction((void*)pData, nFilesize)`

In the masm (receiver):
`masmfunction proc stdcall pSrc:DWORD, _Length:DWORD
    mov esi, pSrc
    mov ecx, _Length`

Comment: The code does indeed look like it works on four *bytes* at a time (`dword ptr [esi]` and `add esi,4`). Dart strings are not sequences of bytes, but of 16-bit UTF-16 code units. If the string is ASCII only, you might get away with treating each character as a byte, but if not, you likely need to UTF-8 encode the string first to get something comparable to the input being hashed. Then you need process those bytes.

Comment: I have followed your advice, with exemple :
`List<int> encoded = utf8.encode("aé");`
Result :  `[97, 195, 169] // a : 97, é : 195, 169`
So, to reach 4 bytes per character, I have to complete with 0 ?
Manually : `[0, 0, 0, 97, 0, 0, 195, 169]`

Comment: You don't need to reach four bytes per char, you need to process four **bytes** at a time. Wherever they come from (e.g. from four code units, from three code units or from one code unit). Also, it seems your code is missing the handling of strings not multiple of four in length. It's probably better to rewrite the cycle to work with DWORDs (4 bytes).

Comment: I added the modified code above following your directions, it does not work. I have the impression that my transcription of the asm algorithm is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transcription of the checksum algorithm is wrong.
Here's how I'd do it:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

int checksum(String string, {Encoding encoder = utf8, Endian endian = Endian.little})
{
    final ByteData bytes = ByteData.sublistView(Uint8List.fromList(encoder.encode(string)));
    int checksum = 0;
    
    
    if (bytes.lengthInBytes >= 4)   
  {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.lengthInBytes; i += 4)
        {
            int chunk = bytes.getUint32(min(i + 4, bytes.lengthInBytes) - 4, endian);
            checksum = (checksum + chunk) ^ ((chunk << 1) + 1 + (chunk >> 31)); 
        }
  }
  
    return checksum & 0xffffffff;
    
}
```

---

You totally missed that:

- The code is working with DWORDs (32-bit integers).
- Strings with less than 4 bytes have zero checksum.
- The code handles strings with length non-multiple of four by reading the last four bytes (that, necessarily, overlap with the previous DWORD).

Here's the commented assembly:

```dart
CHECKSUM32_MACRO MACRO 
   LOCAL Checksum32Loop, Checksum32Done       
        xor     eax,eax                   ;Checksum = 0
        cmp     ecx,4
        jb      Checksum32Done            ;If len < 4 Then Return
    align 16
    Checksum32Loop:
        mov     ebx,dword ptr [esi]       ;c = DWORD from string (**FOUR** bytes)
        add     eax,ebx                   ;Checksum += c
        shl     ebx,1                     ;CF = c[31], c = c << 1
        adc     ebx,1                     ;c += (1 + CF)
        xor     eax,ebx                   ;Checksum ^= c
        add     esi,4                     ;Point to next DWORD
        sub     ecx,4                     ;Len -= 4
        jz      Checksum32Done            ;If Len == 0 Then Return
        cmp     ecx,4                     
        jae     Checksum32Loop            ;If Len >= 4 Then Cycle back
        mov     edx,4                     
        sub     edx,ecx                   ;edx = 4 - Len (left, so it's 4 - Len % 4 in absolute terms)
        sub     esi,edx                   ;Point to last DWORD (Len-4 in absolute terms, go back 4-Len in relative terms)
        mov     ecx,4                     ;Set Len=4 to cycle one more time
        jmp     Checksum32Loop
   Checksum32Done:     
ENDM
```

Also, note that converting numbers to string to extract digits or bits is generally a bad practice. Use the `>>` shift operator instead and eventually an AND.

Comment: Wow, thank you it's really clearer with your explanations, and the good practice advice.
I tested your code with a long string of 464 bytes and the result is correct.
Strangely on a small string as an example, the checksum is different, but once passed in hexadecimal, it is good but with an extra '8' in front.
String myString = "bonjour petit foufou, tu vas bien et bien pas moi. Tu es sur, je ne le suis pas du tout ok";
masm : 564299864 -> 21A28858,
your code : 34924038232 ->821A28858

Comment: @Gaiusfr Oh, that's because dart's `int`s are 64-bit, I thought they were 32-bit. Let me fix that. Ok, I've added `& 0xffffffff` before returning the checksum. If I'm not wrong the intermediate results can be 64-bit and then the final result can be reduced to 32-bit with an AND. This is faster than ANDing at each iteration.

Comment: Yes, that's good!
In the meantime, I found an alternative solution -but less classy than yours ^^'.
`return BigInt.from(checksum).toUnsigned(32).toInt();`

Comment: There is also `n.toUnsigned(32)` directly on `int`, which will effectively just do `n & 0xffffffff`. Going through `BigInt` is very much overkill.